# How to change bean's block view mode programmatically?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have created a block entity using bean module.

It has three image fields. Image1, Image2 and Image3.

I want to show only one image depending upon current time. I have three time values.
For this I have created 3 view modes each for one time value.

Now I'm stuck that how will change the view mode based on time value programmatically.

I have used the following code.

```
function glue_site_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if ($timevalue1 == $value1) {
    $data['content']['bean']['block_delta']['#view_mode'] = 'view_mode1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_entity_view_mode_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7)

```
function MYMODULE_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {  
    if ($timevalue1 == $value1) {  
      $view_mode = 'view_mode1';  
    } elseif {  
      .......  
    }  
}
```